# Alter a value passed by a filter in request to Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to allow the consumers of my API to filter on a datetimefield with auto_now=True. The caveat is that I want them to be able to do so with a UNIX format (ie : 1380783641 instead of 2013-10-02T16:46:24.030321 which is the default format.)

I've already dehydrated the field in order to render it as such with :

```
    def dehydrate_created_on(self, bundle):

        return bundle.data['created_on'].strftime('%s')
```

How can I do the same for the value passed in a request to be filtered on ?

```
/api/v1/model/?created_on__gt=1380783641
```

This returns a ValueError : (in French)

```
"error": [
"Le format de la valeur Â«Â 1380783641Â Â» n'est pas valide. Le format correct est AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][FH]."
]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which version of tastypie are you using?

Comment: @astreal I am using Tastypie 0.9.15, your solution is working just fine (with startswith instead of starts_with) ! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: cool, I'll update the answer for the syntax issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky workaround based on what can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-tastypie/fvCF4P1Qq14) is to redefine the `build_filter` method:

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    if filters is None:
        filters = {}
    orm_filters = super(YourResource, self).build_filters(filters)
    for filt in orm_filters:
        if filt.startswith('created_on'):
            orm_filters[filt] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(filters[filt]))
    return orm_filters
```